# Is prone masturbation harmful?

Tags: sexuality, masturbation

I have been masturbating in prone fashion for 13 years daily, until I found out that [it was considered harmful](http://www.herballove.com/articles/prone-masturbation-what-it-and-why-you-need-stop-doing-it).

Is it true that prone masturbation can lead to anorgasmia or erectile dysfunction?

Comment: Hi mhr. This site is for analysing notable claims, not for personal advice. Please have a look at [The Tour](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.